# Parse python int to Mysql unsigned TINYINT

Tags: python, mysql, uint8t

I'm trying to store an int value which has a range of 0-220 into a TINYINT MySQL column.

```
hr_max = 220
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO variables(member, hr_max) VALUES(%s,%s)",
                (member, hr_max))
self.con.commit()
```

But every time I write something bigger than 127. I get:

> DataError (1264, "Out of range value for column 'hr_max' at row 1")

I've tried parsing the number to uint8 with numpy but if I get the variable bytes count with:

```
sys.getsizeof(hr_max)
```

I get 14

I've tried as char but it complains about it's string and expected was int.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL [TINYINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) has a range of:

> ```
> Type      Storage     Minimum Value     Maximum Value
>           (Bytes)    (Signed/Unsigned)  (Signed/Unsigned)
> TINYINT   1          -128               127
>                      0                  255
> ```

So for a signed TINYINT, anything larger that 127 will cause problems.

Comment: Hi Yes, -128 to 127 when is signed, that's why I'm trying to tell python to tell MySQL that this 220 is unsigned.

Comment: So I can write something up to from 0 to 255

Comment: Only if you have `UNSIGNED`